# How to test for an empty generic.dictionary collection?

Tags: c#, collections, generics, nullreferenceexception

How do I test a generic dictionary object to see whether it is empty?  I want to run some code as follows:

```
while (reportGraphs.MoveNext())
{
    reportGraph = (ReportGraph)reportGraphs.Current.Value;
    report.ContainsGraphs = true;
    break;
}
```

The reportGraph object is of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary
When running this code then the reportGraphs dictionary is empty and MoveNext() immediately throws a NullReferenceException.  I don't want to put a try-catch around the block if there is a more performant way of handling the empty collection.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `reportGraphs` itself isn't `null`?

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` doesn't *have* a `MoveNext()` method. Are you sure you're not thinking of an iterator over a Dictionary?

Comment: Very sorry, reportGraphs is actually defined as the .Enumerator, as in
    reportGraphs = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, ReportGraph>.Enumerator();
So, any way to detect that MoveNext() will throw an exception when applied to the Enumerator.  If I try checking for null I get 
Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,Highpersoft.BusinessModel.ReportGraph>.Enumerator' and '<null>'

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If it's a generic dictionary, you can just check [Dictionary.Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhcy256f(VS.85).aspx).  Count will be 0 if it's empty.

However, in your case, `reportGraphs` looks like it's an `IEnumerator<T>` - is there a reason your enumerating your collection by hand?

Comment: You are correct - it is indeed an enumerator - sorry.  There's no strong reason, its just the way the object model within the app has been structured - changing it would require quite a bit of work...

Comment: It's usually a much better approach to not work with IEnumerator directly - use a foreach loop instead, as it will typically prevent this exact scenario...

Answer (score 8):

There's a difference between an `empty` dictionary and `null`. Calling `MoveNext` on an empty collection won't result in a [`NullReferenceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx). I guess in your case you could test if `reportGraphs != null`.

Comment: reportGraphs looks more like an enumerator than a dictionary though. Why should a dictionary return a `null` enumerator? Just wondering...

Comment: But `Dictionary<K,V>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>`, doesn't it? I believe this it where the `Value` property comes from.

Comment: Yes, sorry folks, it is indeed an enumerator.